# How to get started with Blueprint [CSS Framework]?

Tags: css, css-frameworks

- Is it worth adapting to a css framework or just use the css we all know?
- How to get started with Blueprint [CSS Framework]?
- Any other css frameworks which is really worth a try?

Comment: U can only use any grid based CSS framework if u r the designer and coder both or u can guide the designer.

Comment: You can use the PSD that is provided with blueprint to design around. As you say, just guide the designer and get them to use the grid template PSD. It helps designing anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If not Blueprint, I recommend at least using a CSS reset file, which standardizes many default browser settings that differ across browsers; such as the [Yahoo "YUI Reset CSS"](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/).

Otherwise, if I were you I guess I would just start in the [Blueprint wiki](http://wiki.github.com/joshuaclayton/blueprint-css/) and look through the [tutorials](http://wiki.github.com/joshuaclayton/blueprint-css/tutorials). Then make something of your own!

Answer (score 1):

To determine if it's best to use a css framework or not, you need to look at your overall web design and see how easily you can break it down into elements. If you find yourself using a lot of container divs and floating them all left or right, a CSS framework may be a good idea.

Another reason it may be beneficial to use Blueprint is that you can decrease the amount of CSS you need. Rather than creating a div id for every column or container and putting in a width and height in your CSS file, you can just use the framework and quickly assign a class.

I built Intronis.com using the Blueprint CSS framework. It worked well because it is a very clean site with common elements and it's based on a grid.

I'd use a CSS framework on a case by case basis. Let the design dictate if you use it or not. For some sites it's a good fit. For others it's not.

To get started, download it [here](http://www.blueprintcss.org/), then just unzip the file and put it in a local test environment to try it out.

Also, make sure you take a look at the IE6 CSS included with Blueprint and take note of the .clearfix class that you can use when working with container divs and floating objects.

Answer (score 0):

I've just written a brief tutorial on how to get started with Blueprint CSS, you might like it. http://flowdev.tumblr.com/post/1187039740/blueprint-css-to-grid-or-not-to-grid